# What maybe [] id mean in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Hi i just started learning Haskell from the book Haskell programming from first principles. This is from the phone excercise. Please explain the usage of `maybe [] id`.

```hs
reverset :: Phone -> Char ->[(Digit, Presses)]

 reverset (Phone buttons) c =
   maybe [] id $ find nonEmpty $ map (flip tapsOnButton c) buttons
   where
    nonEmpty [] = False
    nonEmpty _  = True
```

Is it for empty list?

Answer (score 2):

First, let's have a look at the `maybe` function:

```
maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b
```

If `maybe` is applied twice by first passing the empty list (`[]`) and then the `id` function, it results in the `maybe [] id` function:

```
maybe [] id :: Maybe [a] -> [a]
```

What `maybe [] id` produces when given a `Maybe [a]` value depends on which data constructor – either `Just` or `Nothing` – was used to produce this `Maybe [a]` value:

- If it is `Just`, give back the value this data constructor takes, the list.
- If it is `Nothing`, result in the empty list (`[]`).

In other words, `maybe [] id` is equivalent to the following function `extractList`:

```
extractList :: Maybe [a] -> [a]
extractList (Just xs) = xs
extractList Nothing = []
```

Roughly speaking, it "extracts" a list from the context of the possibility of being missing; in this case, if missing, it returns the empty list. Example:

```
ghci> extractList (Just [1,2,3])
[1,2,3]
ghci> extractList Nothing
[]
ghci> extractList (Just [])
[]
```

Note that it produces the same result for the inputs `Just []` and `Nothing`.

Comment: It's an odd way to write it. Most people would opt for the clearer `fromMaybe []`, I think, or the even `concat :: Foldable t => t [a] -> a`, which is just a more general version of your `extractList`.

Comment: @AndrewRay Thank you. I like your approach with `concat`. As far as I understand, it consists of writing the annotation `extractList :: Maybe [a] -> [a]` and then simply `extractList = concat`. It made me think `maybe []` can be implemented in terms of `foldMap` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b
```

Quote from documentation

> The maybe function takes a default value, a function, and a Maybe value. If the Maybe value is Nothing, the function returns the default value. Otherwise, it applies the function to the value inside the Just and returns the result.